# Can't choose tomcat for 'smart tomcat' plugin in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, kotlin

I"m trying to add tomcat to Smart tomcat plugin
Using these "3 dots" button in [Run/Debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY1S2.png) but nothing happens except the fact that idea fails with exception

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "idea-path\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc/bin/java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "idea-path\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc/bin/java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.utils.PluginUtils.getTomcatInfo(PluginUtils.java:58)
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.utils.PluginUtils.getTomcatInfo(PluginUtils.java:30)
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.setting.TomcatSetting$1.run(TomcatSetting.java:58)
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.setting.TomcatSetting$1.run(TomcatSetting.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.ToolbarDecorator$2.doAdd(ToolbarDecorator.java:440)
    at com.intellij.ui.CommonActionsPanel$Buttons.performAction(CommonActionsPanel.java:60)
    at com.intellij.ui.CommonActionsPanel$MyActionButton.actionPerformed(CommonActionsPanel.java:272)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:357)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:837)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:762)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:694)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:427)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1678)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.lambda$show$0(SettingsDialog.java:69)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.show(SettingsDialog.java:69)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:97)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.perform(ShowSettingsAction.java:63)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowSettingsAction.java:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:301)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:307)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:291)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:528)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:548)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:837)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:762)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "idea-path\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc/bin/java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.utils.PluginUtils.getTomcatInfo(PluginUtils.java:40)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 111 more
```

No spaces in the path to tomcat,
as well as no space in my path to idea.

Smart Tomcat version 2.6

Tomcat 8.0.30

Java 1.8.0_161

Kotlin plugin 1.3.0-release-IJ.2018.1-1

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.3986.9, built on February 28, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b16 amd64`enter code here`
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Why this happens?
Why does 'smart tomcat' requires this 'java' under kotlin plugin?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by copying "java.exe" to the folder where it's required "idea-path\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc/bin/java"

Comment: what's the full absolute path? you wrote only a partial path

Comment: I'm trying to configure my java version for smart tomcat too so this clarification would help.